# Can STM32F401 Nucleo boards can be integrated with Ethernet boards?

Tags: embedded, stm32, stm32f4discovery, stm32f4

Hi I know STM32F401 Discovery boards and STM32F407 boards can be used to integrate with external Ethernet boards (DP83848). But I need to know whether I can use STM32F401 Nucleo boards (STM32-F401RE) to connect with external Ethernet boards?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not a software question, so off-topic.  Perhaps https://electronics.stackexchange.com/, but better to re-word as "how...?" rather than ""can...?" - the answer is probably yes, but that does not get you much further does it?  Also the answer will be specific to "Ethernet board" in question since "Ethernet board" could cover everything from a full NIC to just a MAC or PHY or even a UART<->Ethernet bridge.  In particular AFAIK, "DP83848" is not a board, but a chip - the answer may depend on what else is on a particular board.

Comment: Pre-empting what you might find on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/, and reading the DP83848 datasheet, the DP83848 is a PHY.  You need a MAC to communicate with it and the 401 lacks a MAC (I doubt your assertion about 401 based discovery boards and DP83848).  You would need a combined MAC/PHY such as https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/en542414 which uses the an SPI interface,  and then you might be on your own for a driver for your chosen IP stack.  Simpler to just get a Nucleo board for a part that already has a MAC.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It exactly provides what I needed.

Comment: To be clear, that is a comment not an "answer" in SO terms.  If you post your question on electronics.stackexchange.com, I will gladly post an answer.